# Input Function to Name File when saving

Tags: python, file, input, save

I want to ask the user of my code to input the desired name of the file f.e. 123456.xlsx. I am closing/saving the file with `wb.Save()`. Now I want to input f.e. the folowing path: 'H:\Desktop\Example\123456.xlsx'. Now I want to work with the input function so the user can always change the desired name of the finished document so: 'H:\Desktop\Example\input('Desired name of file').xlsx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you have found the problem exactly, but this should work:

```
output_file_name = input("Please enter the output file name:\n> ")

# Your work code here

# Then save the file
wb.save(r'H:\Desktop\Example\{}.xlsx'.format(output_file_name))
```

Comment: This solution returns the error: Save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
filename = input("choose file name")
```

and then you could use `f'H:\Desktop\Exemple\{filename}.xlsx'`

Answer (score 0):

you would use the + operator to concatenate strings

```
wb.save('H:\Desktop\Example\' + input("file name to save as") + ".xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like-

```
wb.save(f'H:\Desktop\Exemple\{input("Your File name: ")}.xlsx')
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

At first it didn't work out but after just reopening the file and saving it again. It worked perfectly, just like explained by @jail_BM.